# "Insert item into a list inside a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

after reading about the List class for a while i couldnt find any remedy for this problem, i need to insert value into an a list item that is held inside the main list.

a List of class Person, holds another list within it called Blocks, Blocks is an int Lost of Blocks addresses held for later use in the tool.

i tried using the insert method of the class List to insert the value of "block" into the List Blocks as follows:

`_person.Insert(stuff, _person.Select(x => x.Blocks.Add(block)));`

where **block** is an int that holds the value to be inserted.
and **stuff** is the int index of Blocks found by IndexOf

but that raised an error marked below the Select clause with the description of

> "Error    8   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\NOOP\NOOP_Tools\DLC.cs  112 39  NOOP_Tools"

as i understand the error is within the select statement, but i m not sure where i m going wrong..

PS, i couldn't comment to one of the replies holding a close answer to what i m facing due to my low reputation, which pushed me to search for other answers but reached nowhere, therefore, i had to raise a question to make sure that i learn what i m doing wrong.

thanks in advance

**EDIT1**

```
 public Action<Person, int> InsertBlockAction = (Class, block) => Class.Blocks.Add(block);

 public Action<Person, string> InserDataAction = (Class, data) => Class.Data = data;
```

i think this might be the answer. still need to test it.

**EDIT2**
the above Actions would only work for each var item in the List

Comment: Why are you calling `Add` in the `Select` clause?

Comment: i m trying to add "block" value into the "Blocks List", i tried using the Insert, but that was not successful either. so i went back into using the Select instead.

Comment: You're calling both `Insert` and `Add`, so it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Maybe some sample data, inputs and expected outputs would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate a particular item in the list, you'll need to select it first somehow, so:

```
var personToEdit = _person[stuff]; // You said 'stuff' is your index

personToEdit.Blocks.Add(block);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
_person.Select(x => x.Blocks.Add(block))
```

`Select` requires a function that *returns* a value - you are just calling `Add` for some unknown reason.  Since `Add` does not return a value, it is not a valid projection.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, Select expects a value to be produced as it is performing a projection.

From what I understand, all you're really looking for is an easy way to add to an inner list against a list of items.

I've come up with the following extension class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddNested<TOuter, TInner>(
        this IEnumerable<TOuter> outerItems,
        Func<TOuter, ICollection<TInner>> innerCollectionSelector,
        Func<TOuter, bool> outerPredicate,
        Func<TOuter, TInner> innerProducer
    )
    {
        foreach(var outer in outerItems)
        {
            innerCollectionSelector(outer).Add(innerProducer(outer));
        }
    }

    public static void AddNested<TOuter, TInner>(
        this IEnumerable<TOuter> outerItems,
        Func<TOuter, ICollection<TInner>> innerCollectionSelector,
        Func<TOuter, bool> outerPredicate,
        TInner innerItemToAdd
    )
    {
        outerItems.AddNested(innerCollectionSelector, outerPredicate, _ => innerItemToAdd);
    }

    public static void AddNested<TOuter, TInner>(
        this IEnumerable<TOuter> outerItems,
        Func<TOuter, ICollection<TInner>> innerCollectionSelector,
        TOuter outerItem,
        Func<TOuter, TInner> innerProducer
    )
    {
        outerItems.AddNested(innerCollectionSelector, i => i.Equals(outerItem), innerProducer);
    }

    public static void AddNested<TOuter, TInner>(
        this IEnumerable<TOuter> outerItems,
        Func<TOuter, ICollection<TInner>> innerCollectionSelector,
        TOuter outerItem,
        TInner innerItemToAdd
    )
    {
        outerItems.AddNested(innerCollectionSelector, outerItem, _ => innerItemToAdd);
    }
}
```

Sticking with your people and blocks lists, you can do something like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Add a new block for everyone called Bob
    people.AddNested(p => p.Blocks, p => p.FirstName == "Bob", p => new Block("Block For Bob"));

    // Add a new block for Bob Mackey
    people.AddNested(p => p.Blocks, p => p.FirstName == "Bob" && p.Surname == "Mackey", 
        p => new Block());

    // Add for specific item
    var person = people.Single(p => p.Surname == "dfsdfdfsdf");
    var block = CreateBlockForPerson(person);
    people.NestedAdd(p => p.Blocks, person, block);
}
```

> **NOTE**: The last scenario in my example only works if `people` actually contains `person`, it'd just silently fail to add the `block` to `person`.